# direction parameter in singlesourceshortestpath function in org.neo4j.graphalgo libraris

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

I am using betweennesscentrality function provided by graphalgo library for calculating betweenness centrality in a project. This function uses SingleSourceShortestPathDijkstra() function which takes a parameter with type of Direction. Direction is an enum with three possible values (INCOMING, OUTGOING and BOTH). I cant understand how does this parameter works and how these values affect the algorithm flow and the final output. I want to calculate betweenness centrality of nodes in a directed weighted graph. to which value should I set the direction parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The direction parameter for this kind of bidirectional traversal has a meaning of

OUTGOING
: from your start and end node we follow relationships only in outgoing direction (in the same direction of the "arrow")

INCOMING
: from your start and end node we follow relationships only in incoming direction (in the opposite direction of the "arrow")

BOTH
: we don't take care about the direction. In most use cases for djikstra, that is the right choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I have two questions. 
First Results of betweenness centrality are slightly different while using outgoing value, from incoming value. But I think the should be the same in both cases because we just have changed the direction not cost of the relationship, I don't understand this issue.
And the second question is that "Does it mean that for finding shortest path with direction value as both, it finds shortest path in an undirected graph"?

Comment: 1) no. If you use INCOMING or OUTGOING the traversals from start and end node solely use the prescribed direction - of course you're graph looks different for incoming or outgoing 2) yes - directions are basically ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think your answer for the first question is right if we consider shortest path between two nodes. but for calculating betweenness centrality of a node we consider the number of shortest paths that pass through the node so the directoin of the shortest path is not important. for example if a node exist in the shortest path from node a to node b in incoming direction, it exist in the shortest path from node b to node a in outgoing direction too. so the overall number of shortest paths sould be the same and consequently betweenness should be the same too.